# Pull only specified part of the data when webscraping

Tags: web-scraping, powerbi, powerquery, m

I am using Power Bi to scrape data from the web to then show the results in a table. 
I have one data table which I then want to link to the scraped data.

I am trying to invoke a function based on when I select a reference in my data table so that power bi only scrapes the selected reference instead of trying to pull back 1000s of rows of data which take a really long time to do!

My data source has approximately just over 1000 rows of data and I am using a web page to show everything that is related.

I have spend some time looking to web scraping and therefore built a scraper function with code below

My table is a distinct list which I then add the custom column to invoke my function and then capture the errors if the Reference does not exist.

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://websiteaddress?Reference=" & Name)),   
    Data = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type datetime}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type date}, {"Column10", type text}, {"Column11", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Expected when I select reference aaa123 in my data table then scrape the website and return the details for that reference in my chart.

I don't want to scrape everything in my Data Table each time on refresh.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "select a reference" in your table? Like when you click on a cell? You could use VBA to track that and feed that into a query so only data for the selected cell is returned or refreshed.

Comment: So PowerBI should scrape the website based on the clicks in the report? Like a direct query to a database? I don't think that's possible with this type of connector, only with databases and SSAS cubes

Comment: Yes Wedge/Gigga, sorry for not being clear in my question. Because the data that I need is usually over 1000 records it takes a really long time to load It all.